# Android - Best way to show data without large amount of layout files

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, expandablelistview

Thanks for all the help recently! Another question!

In the app I'm building, I currently have a layout file with an expandable lstview where you can choose 10 options. When you choose one of those options, you pick another 4 options. From picking the week, you then have 3 more options. Each of those 3 options will currently open a new activity that has a listview with a checkbox and textview in each row, with about 10 rows each.

Instead of making 30 layout files which will probably crash the app(not sure how many it would take to crash the app), I'm thinking there has to be a better way. I have looked it up and can't really find what I'm looking for. I have read a little bit about sqlite, but wouldn't you still need separate layout files to call different parts of the tables? Is there a way to make a single layout file with a list view, and fill the listview with different data from sqlite, depending on where the click came from in the expandable list view?

For example, if they click workout 29 on expandable list view, then click Week 1, then click Day 1.. can that single layout load data from sqlite db. Then if they were to go back and say click workout 30, week 2, day 3, that same layout load different info from the db?

I'm also trying to find out how to make a double expandable list view still

Thanks again!

Comment: It would take thousands of layout files to crash an app.  An app with only 30 is still fairly small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a SQLite database for all your data (unless you plan on holding the data in memory which is not a good idea if it is a rather large amount). You should just create a simple view and keep reusing it. What you will have to do is create your own adapter (extending from BaseExpandableListAdapter for Expandable list views and BaseAdapter for normal list views) and then query the SQLite databse table for the data that you need.

If you are only displaying String items, you can directly extend ArrayAdapter and then provide the array of items that you want to display for the normal list.

As far as crashing goes, there are many apps that have well over 30 layout files. Besides even if you did start loading a lot of views, Android will automatically start destroying views as it starts running low on memory and recreate them when it is needed to do so.

Comment: Thank you! I think I should be okay without the database then, since all the data are single line strings that are calculations of previous numbers gathered! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So this is very simple all you have to do is create a DataAdapter for the listview. You can then add list view items which bind to the onclick listener and then you can clear that list and add new elements to it. a useful link would be.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Thank you! I think I should be okay without the database then, since all the data are single line strings that are calculations of previous numbers gathered! Thanks!

Comment: Remember views are very heavy when they have children it will cause your app to load slowly. If you have minimal child views then it will be faster. That's why building a one dimensional list view and clearing it on click is better because then you don't have a huge tree that android then calls the built-in function to redraw everything. If I were to change a child it re-draws all parents of that child and its brothers and sisters essentially.